How to connect EKS to jenkins behind ALB with JNLP?
I have a jenkins running on EC2 behind ALB,
on the other aws account I have EKS with Fargate profile.
I'm trying to run jenkins agents on fargate using the Kubernetes plugin (Can't use the ECS plugin for other reason)
I get connection rejected:
The logs indicate that the connection to the Jenkins master is being rejected because the acknowledgment sequence expected by the JNLP4 protocol is not being received
I found that this is due to jnlp traffic from jenkins that can't pass through ALB, and needs to be transfered raw ,using NLB with tcp 50000 port connection.
please assist, I don't want to change my jenkins setup.
Tried alpine image, but the issue is with the ack type (jnlp)

With a similar setup, I solved using the WebSocket connection (see here) to connect the agents over HTTPS.
If you are using SSL termination on the ALB, with a self-signed certificate, you need also to build a custom inbound-agent base image (see here) with the CA certificate.

I defined alpine as the jnlp default, and I still can't connect back to jenkins, getting :
jenkins-jobs/alpine-kdt37-f0ccj Container jnlp was terminated (Exit Code: 255, Reason: Error)

jnlp -- terminated (255)
-----Logs-------------
Caused by: io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.core.HandshakeException: Response code was not 101: 400.

